# Inyectar diferentes tipos de la misma clase

Tags: java, inyeccion-de-dependencias

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio con `@Inject` de paquete `javax.inject` y no tengo problema por ejemplo cuando en una clase creo algo como esto

```
public class Persona {
    @Inject 
    private Rol rol;
}
```

pero cuando intento hacer lo siguiente, me marca que es ambigua

```
public class Persona {
    @Inject 
    private Rol rol;
    @Inject 
    private List<Rol> roles;
}
```

Se que puedo usar Qualifiers pero el tema es que es la misma clase de la cual quiero tener rol como un solo objeto y roles como multiples objetos de rol,

Hasta ahora solo inyecto el objeto unico y la lista de roles la inicializo de la manera normal

```
List<Rol> roles = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar un conjunto de [`Any`](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/1.2/javax/enterprise/inject/Any.html) e [`Instance`](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/1.2/javax/enterprise/inject/Instance.html) para lo que necesitas. El beneficio de `Instance` es que es un `Iterable`, por ende puedes aplicar un `for` loop mejorado:

```
@Inject
@Any
private Instance<Rol> roles;
```

---

Respuesta adaptada de: [Inject list of objects in CDI (Weld)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4010642/1065197)